# Parse XML to Object in Android application

Tags: android, xml, parsing, saxparser

I want to create an android application get xml data from server and parse XML data to object. 
 I want to parse below data to 5 List:

```
private List<TaskScheduleDto> TaskShedule;
 private List<ContractOptionInListDto> ContractOptionInList;
 private List<ContractOptionOutListDto> ContractOptionOutList;
 private List<OutsourceListDto> OutsourceList;
 private List<CheckListDto> CheckList;
```

This is my XML data.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response>
    <ReturnCode>0</ReturnCode>
    <Message></Message>
    <Result>
        <Task>
            <TaskShedule>
                <building_id>1</building_id>
                <room_id>12</room_id>
                <building_name>Gacon</building_name>
                <room_name>Lala</room_name>
                <management_area_name>Heocon</management_area_name>
            </TaskShedule>

            <ContractOptionInList>
                <ContractOption>
                    <task_shedule_id>2</task_shedule_id>
                    <contract_option_id>2</contract_option_id>
                     <task_kbn>2</task_kbn>
                    <option_name>2</option_name>
                    <status>1</status>
                </ContractOption>
            </ContractOptionInList>

            <ContractOptionOutList>
                <ContractOption>
                    <task_shedule_id>2</task_shedule_id>
                    <contract_option_id>2</contract_option_id>
                     <task_kbn>2</task_kbn>
                    <option_name>2</option_name>
                    <status>1</status>
                </ContractOption>
            </ContractOptionOutList>

            <Outsourece>
                    <task_shedule_id>2</task_shedule_id>
                    <outsource_id>2</outsource_id>
                    <purpose>2</purpose>
                    <memo>2</memo>
                    <fixed_date>1</fixed_date>
                    <date_type>2</date_type>
                    <contract_option_id>2</contract_option_id>
                    <variable_count>2</variable_count>
                    <status>2</status>
            </Outsourece>

            <CheckList>
                <task_shedule_id></task_shedule_id>
                <Group>
                    <code>123</code>
                    <name>Heoheo</name>
                    <CheckItem>
                        <check_item>Lalala</check_item>
                        <check_detail>9987</check_detail>
                        <status>1</status>
                        <code>011</code>
                    </CheckItem>
                </Group>
            </CheckList>
        </Task>
    </Result>
</Response>
```

How I can do that?
Any help much appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this, done as per your requirement, but add more to complete this. hope this will help you, also add setter methods to each class., bcz I am using setter methods here.

Eg:
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

import android.provider.Telephony.Mms.Addr;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyModeXMLParser {


    private List<TaskScheduleDto> TaskShedule;
     private List<ContractOptionInListDto> ContractOptionInList;
     private List<ContractOptionOutListDto> ContractOptionOutList;
     private List<OutsourceListDto> OutsourceList;
     private List<CheckListDto> CheckList;



    public  void parse(FileInputStream is) {
        XmlPullParserFactory factory = null;
        XmlPullParser parser = null;
        try {
            factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            parser = factory.newPullParser();
            parser.setInput(is, null);

            int eventType = parser.getEventType();

            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

                String tagname = parser.getName();
                switch (eventType) {

                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:   
//          create the objects for classes when getting a class name as open tag

                                                if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("TaskShedule")) 
                                                {  taskScheduleDto = new TaskScheduleDto();

                                                }

                                                else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("ContractOptionInList")) 
                                                {  contractOptionInListDto = new ContractOptionInListDto();

                                                }

                                                else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("ContractOptionOutList")) 
                                                {  contractOptionOutListDto = new ContractOptionOutListDto();

                                                }

                                                else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("Outsourece")) 
                                                {  outsourceListDto = new OutsourceListDto();

                                                }

                                                else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("CheckList")) 
                                                {  checkListDto = new CheckListDto();

                                                }

                                                break;

                case XmlPullParser.TEXT:        
//  GETTING TEXT ENCLOSED BY ANY TAG
                                                text = parser.getText();                    
                                                break;

                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:     if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("TaskShedule")) 
                                                {  
//          ADD THE OBJECT TO LIST WHILE GETTING THE END TAG
                                                    TaskShedule.add(taskScheduleDto);

                                                }

//          SET THE VALUE OF EACH MEMBERS OF THE CLASS
                                                    else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("building_id")) {
                                                        taskScheduleDto.setBuildingID(text);
                                                    }
                                                    else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("room_id>")) {
                                                        taskScheduleDto.setRoomID(text);
                                                    }
                                                    else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("building_name")) {
                                                        taskScheduleDto.setBuildingName(text);
                                                    }
                                                    else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("room_name")) {
                                                        taskScheduleDto.setRoomName(text);
                                                    }
                                                    else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("management_area_name")) {
                                                        taskScheduleDto.setManagmentAreaName(text);
                                                    }


                                                else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("ContractOptionInList")) 
                                                {  ContractOptionInList.add(contractOptionInListDto);

                                                }

//              SET THE VALUE OF EACH MEMBERS OF THE CLASS
//          replace it with your required!
//                                                  else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("building_id")) {
//                                                  taskScheduleDto.setBuildingID(text);
//                                                  }
//                                                  else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("room_id>")) {
//                                                      taskScheduleDto.setRoomID(text);
//                                                  }
//                                                  else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("building_name")) {
//                                                      taskScheduleDto.setBuildingName(text);
//                                                  }
//                                                  else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("room_name")) {
//                                                      taskScheduleDto.setRoomName(text);
//                                                  }
//                                                  else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("management_area_name")) {
//                                                      taskScheduleDto.setManagmentAreaName(text);
//                                                  }


                                                else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("ContractOptionOutList")) 
                                                {  ContractOptionOutList.add(contractOptionOutListDto);

                                                }

//              SET THE VALUE OF EACH MEMBERS OF THE CLASS
//          replace it with your required!
//                                                  else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("building_id")) {
//                                                  taskScheduleDto.setBuildingID(text);
//                                                  }
//                                                  else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("room_id>")) {
//                                                      taskScheduleDto.setRoomID(text);
//                                                  }
//                                                  else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("building_name")) {
//                                                      taskScheduleDto.setBuildingName(text);
//                                                  }
//                                                  else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("room_name")) {
//                                                      taskScheduleDto.setRoomName(text);
//                                                  }
//                                                  else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("management_area_name")) {
//                                                      taskScheduleDto.setManagmentAreaName(text);
//                                                  }



                                                else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("Outsourece")) 
                                                {  OutsourceList.add(outsourceListDto);

                                                }

//              SET THE VALUE OF EACH MEMBERS OF THE CLASS
//          replace it with your required!
//                                                  else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("building_id")) {
//                                                  taskScheduleDto.setBuildingID(text);
//                                                  }
//                                                  else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("room_id>")) {
//                                                      taskScheduleDto.setRoomID(text);
//                                                  }
//                                                  else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("building_name")) {
//                                                      taskScheduleDto.setBuildingName(text);
//                                                  }
//                                                  else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("room_name")) {
//                                                      taskScheduleDto.setRoomName(text);
//                                                  }
//                                                  else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("management_area_name")) {
//                                                      taskScheduleDto.setManagmentAreaName(text);
//                                                  }

                                                else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("CheckList")) 
                                                {  CheckList.add(checkListDto);


//                                              SET THE VALUE OF EACH MEMBERS OF THE CLASS
//                                              replace it with your required!
//                                                                                      else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("building_id")) {
//                                                                                      taskScheduleDto.setBuildingID(text);
//                                                                                      }
//                                                                                      else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("room_id>")) {
//                                                                                          taskScheduleDto.setRoomID(text);
//                                                                                      }
//                                                                                      else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("building_name")) {
//                                                                                          taskScheduleDto.setBuildingName(text);
//                                                                                      }
//                                                                                      else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("room_name")) {
//                                                                                          taskScheduleDto.setRoomName(text);
//                                                                                      }
//                                                                                      else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("management_area_name")) {
//                                                                                          taskScheduleDto.setManagmentAreaName(text);
//                                                                                      }   
                                                } break;

                default:                        break;
                }


                eventType = parser.next();

            }

        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

you can refer to XML Pullparser and sample code here : http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/xml/android-simple-xmlpullparser-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Please try out https://gitlab.com/mvysny/konsume-xml . It's also StAX-based, but introduces a higher-level API which is easier to use.

The code would look like follows:

```
data class TaskSchedule(val buildingId: Int, val roomId: Int, val buildingName: String, val roomName: String,
                        val managementAreaName: String) {
    companion object {
        fun xml(k: Konsumer): TaskSchedule {
            k.checkCurrent("TaskShedule")
            return TaskSchedule(k.childInt("building_id"),
                    k.childInt("room_id"),
                    k.childText("building_name"),
                    k.childText("room_name"),
                    k.childText("management_area_name"))
        }
    }
}

val taskScheduleList = mutableListOf<TaskSchedule>()
File("src/test/files/example.xml").konsumeXml().use { k ->
    k.child("Response") {
        childText("ReturnCode") // skip over <ReturnCode>
        childText("Message") // skip over <Message>
        child("Result") {
            child("Task") {
                child("TaskShedule") {
                    taskScheduleList.add(TaskSchedule.xml(this))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
println(taskScheduleList)
```

This would print `[TaskSchedule(buildingId=1, roomId=12, buildingName=Gacon, roomName=Lala, managementAreaName=Heocon)]`. The advantage of this approach is that konsume-xml will also check the XML for validity - any unknown tags fail the parse with meaningful error message.

Disclaimer: I'm the author.